# How do I get the right $.ajax data type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

could you please help with this. I have the following javascript:

```
$('form').click(function (e)
           {
            if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'SubmitAddLevel')
            {
                var parent = $('#' + e.target.getAttribute('attr')),
                var Data = [];
                parent.find('.input').children().each(function (i, e)
                {
                  Data.push(e.getAttribute('id') + ":" + e.value);
                    console.log(Data);
                });                

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'AjaxControls.aspx/CreateUserLevel',
                    //data: Data, //.join(','),
                    dataType: "text",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //error: function (er) { alert(er); },
                    success: function (response)
                    {

                        if (response.d === "true")
                        {

                            $("#ErrorDivAddLevel").html('Level created successfully!').fadeIn('slow');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#SuccessDivAddLevel").html('Level creation failed!').fadeIn('slow');
                        }
                    },

                });
            }
```

The result of 'Data' I got on the console is :["LevelNameAddLevel:Admin", "PriviledgeIDAddLevels:|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|"]. How do I convert this to what ajax will pass to my web menthod?

Here is the web method

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
 Public Shared Function CreateUserLevel(userLevel As String, userPriviledges As String) As String

 return "true"

end function
```

Comment: what is the data expected in the server, what are the data types and parameters expected

Comment: can you show the signature of the web method

Comment: just a little edit suggestion: change `response.d === "true"` => `response.d === true`. Also, if you are looking for the text response in your success, use the `response.responseText`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Data should look something more like this:

```
[{"LevelNameAddLevel":"Admin"}, {"PriviledgeIDAddLevels":"|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|"}]
```

So you have key / value pairs inside of an array. In the request, you should then be able to fetch the data via the keys in the request. 
But I'm not quite sure what this is supposed to mean : "|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|"